# Swift - how to make custom header for UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I need to add custom header to my table

I try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 18))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50))
    label.text = "TEST TEXT"
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.view.addSubview(view)

    return view
}
```

but this doesn't work, I see nothing on table

What am I doing wrong ? Or maybe there is another ways ?

Comment: Adding `view` to `self.view` is not necessary. It will be removed from there and added to the table view.

Comment: @Cyrille I'm not sure why you think the view would be removed after it's been programmatically added to the subviews array, but it seems to me it would  simply be added to the view hierarchy in two different places, which would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Nope. A view can only have one superview at a time. If you add a view anywhere, it will first be removed from where it was previously.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you set the section header height in the viewDidLoad?

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 70
```

Plus you should replace

```
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

by

```
view.addSubview(label)
```

Finally you have to check your frames

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
```

and eventually the desired text color as it seems to be currently white on white.

Answer (score 85):

**The best working Solution of adding Custom header view in UITableView for section in swift 4 is --**

#1 first Use method ViewForHeaderInSection as below -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
        label.text = "Notification Times"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = .yellow
        
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        
        return headerView
    }
```

#2 Also Don't forget to set Height of the header using heightForHeaderInSection UITableView method -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

and you're all set    [image: Check it here in image]

Comment: Please let me know if we can improve this 

Comment: You dont have to add additional view there you can create UILabel directly as header. **let headerView = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50)), headerView.text = "Notification Times"**

Comment: Thanks for writing back @Hope, yes we can do same as you suggested, I just make it because I need to follow my UI as per Zeplin (the reason I wrote "my custom Colour & font") :)

Comment: view Hide with Scrolling issue

Comment: Hi @KrunalNagvadia, what issue you're facing?

Comment: When i Scroll my headerView is disappear. This is my code

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       return headerView
    }`

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia I believe you want to keep the header view visible until all the cells are visible for the section. for the same, you need to change the table style in attribute inspector as Grouped.

Hope I answer you, if still not please be specific about your problem and the code you tried.

Comment: This is a section header, not a table header.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using custom cell as header, add the following.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView()
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell") as! CustomTableCell
        headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
        return headerView
    }
```

If you want to have simple view, add the following.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let headerView:UIView =  UIView()
    return headerView
}
```

Comment: nice. but since the cell is a view you can return it directly i beieve.

Answer (score 34):

**This worked for me - Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell") as! CustomTableCell
        return headerCell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I've added a header cell manually and had to offset the cells in the appropriate delegate methods. This'll save some work

Comment: It worked for me, when I add `heightForHeaderInSection` along with `viewForHeaderInSection`. I have created another table cell in the tableview of storyboard and given different identifier. This worked!

Answer (score 26):

If you are willing to use custom table header as table header, try the followings....

Updated for swift 3.0

**Step 1**

Create UITableViewHeaderFooterView for custom header..

```
import UIKit

class MapTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

}
```

Step 2

Add custom header to UITableView

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self

            //register the header view

            let nibName = UINib(nibName: "CustomHeaderView", bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(nibName, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderView")


    }

    extension BranchViewController : UITableViewDelegate{

    }

    extension BranchViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 200
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomHeaderView" ) as! MapTableHeaderView

            return headerView
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 

    Int) -> Int {
            // retuen no of rows in sections
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
            // retuen your custom cells    
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // retuen no of sections
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            // retuen height of row
        }


    }
```

Comment: Very Nice bro. I learnt to manage code using extension as well. Thanks for the full code format! :)

Answer (score 8):

add `label` to `subview` of custom `view`, no need of `self.view.addSubview(view)`, because `viewForHeaderInSection` return the `UIView`

```
view.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: You need to add the label, yes ; but adding `view` to `self.view` is not necessary. It will be removed from there and added to the table view.

Answer (score 4):

I have had some problems in Swift 5 with this. When using this function I had a wrong alignment with the header cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell") as! CustomTableCell
     return headerCell
}
```

The cell view was shown with a bad alignment and the top part of the tableview was shown. So I had to make some tweak like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 90))
     let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER")
     headerCell?.frame = headerView.bounds
     headerView.addSubview(headerCell!)
     return headerView
 }
```

I am having this problem in Swift 5 and Xcode 12.0.1, I don't know if it is just a problem for me or it is a bug. Hope it helps ! I have lost a morning...

Comment: Finally someone who solved my problem. Big thanks to you!

Comment: I lost some time too, so I am very glad to help. I don't know why in this last Xcode versions this function has end working, because in other projects it works fine.