# How to set the color text color for a UITableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an app that was displaying correctly until I updated to IOS 13.

In the old version of the app ( before iOS 13 ) the header text color was displayed correctly. See below.

[image]

Now the header displays this way:

[image]

I didn't change anything, so I assume something changed on Apple's side of things.
This is how I am setting the header text color:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = Styles.greyColor()
    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = Styles.mainColor()
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
}
```

The color it's asking for is created like this:

```
static func greyColor() -> UIColor{
    return uicolorFromHex(0x9B9B9B)
}

static func mainColor() -> UIColor {
    // blue background
    //return uicolorFromHex(0x222C45)
    return uicolorFromHex(0x1B2337)
}
```

This might have been something that has been discussed, but I can't seem to find any recent posts about it.

Comment: Under the summary of UITableViewHeaderFooterView it says: "You can also assign an optional background view to the background view property." Isn't that what I am trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - how to make custom header for UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964941/swift-how-to-make-custom-header-for-uitableview)

Comment: can you try `header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: same results, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding:                 
header.contentView.backgroundColor = Styles.mainColor()

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by adding:

```
header.contentView.backgroundColor = Styles.mainColor()
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.

Comment: Good answer!  I think you can accept your own answer as well (adds the green check + more rep for you), right?